# What's the difference between nauseous and nauseated?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences, comparisons

I read an [article](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/health/disease-health/differences-between-nauseated-and-nauseous/) about the difference between nauseous and nauseated:

It seems the article at last indicate that both nauseous and nauseated can mean the state of wanting to vomit.  Is that true?  Is that a mistake that too many people make so people basically accept this misusage as correct one?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nauseous http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nauseated

Comment: From your linked article: 'Nausea by itself is a phenomenon of wanting to vomit. It is a discomfort or uneasiness in the upper stomach and thus, creates a feeling of the urge to vomit.' After reading these two sentences, I'd avoid this website like the plague.

Comment: The article seems quite clear in its premise: that the words are actually different but **commonly used** as synonyms, which it finds regrettable. Given that MW appears to concur, and dictionaries reflect usage, it would seem the article is right. What is the question?

Comment: Just never use *nauseous* and no one will be confused. Only use *nauseated* when you have nausea yourself, and use ***nauseating*** when something imparts nausea to others.

Comment: I confess that this is one of my pet peeves.  Whenever I hear someone say "I feel nauseous", I have to restrain myself from answering "I know - just listening to you makes me want to puke."

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as [general reference](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nauseous): "Traditional critics have insisted that *nauseous* is properly used only to mean 'causing nausea' and that it is incorrect to use it to mean 'affected with nausea'... Since there is a lot of evidence to show that *nauseous* is widely used to mean 'feeling sick,' it appears that people use *nauseous* mainly in the sense in which it is considered incorrect. In its 'correct' sense it is being supplanted by *nauseating*." That seems to answer your question exactly.

Comment: @apsillers - Given that this comes up frequently in "words commonly misused" lists and that there is general disagreement about what is correct, I think it's not necessarily as general reference as it may appear at first glance.

Comment: This is rather like the "healthy" and "healthful" debate, isn't it? Strictly, a person is *healthy* while a food is *healthful*. But that doesn't stop people from calling foods "healthy", and it is fairly accepted usage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Nausea](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nausea), by itself, is the urge to vomit.

> I had really bad nausea.

[Nauseated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseated?show=0&t=1378693194) is the verb meaning to become affected with nausea.

> I felt really nauseated all of a sudden.

[Nauseating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseating) is the quality of inflicting nausea on someone.

> Man, that smell was really nauseating.

[Nauseous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseous) is the weird one, which can mean *either* 'nauseated' or 'nauseating'.  Some folks [definitely believe](http://hellogiggles.com/10-words-that-youve-probably-been-misusing) that its only proper use is 'nauseating', but Merriam Webster's usage notes disagree:

> Those who insist that *nauseous* can properly be used only in sense 1 ["causing nausea or disgust : NAUSEATING"] and that in sense 2 ["affected with nausea or disgust"] it is an error for *nauseated* are mistaken. Current evidence shows these facts: *nauseous* is most frequently used to mean physically affected with nausea, usu. after a linking verb such as *feel* or *become*; figurative use is quite a bit less frequent. Use of *nauseous* in sense 1 is much more often figurative than literal, and this use appears to be losing ground to *nauseating*. *Nauseated* is used more widely than *nauseous* in sense 2.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I think English language's mechanism of using inflection/derivation to indicate different word functions is inherently confusing.

Answer (score 6):

***The story of 'nauseous' as told by Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionaries***

The history of *nauseous* in Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series is quite interesting. As late as the *Sixth Collegiate* (1949), MW's entry for *nauseous* has just one definition:

> **nauseous** *adj.* Causing, or fitted to cause, nausea; disgusting.

The *Sixth Collegiate* was MW's Collegiate Dictionary of record until 1963 (my copy is copyrighted 1959). But the *Seventh Collegiate* (1963) contains a radically altered the entry for *nauseous*:

> **nauseous** *adj.* **1 :** NAUSEATED **2 :** causing nausea : SICKENING

Not only does *nauseous* as "nauseated" make its debut in the *Seventh Collegiate*, but it occupies the first (that is, chronologically earlier) meaning of the word, bumping *nauseous* as "nauseating" to the second slot in the entry.

In the *Eighth Collegiate* (1973), Merriam-Webster reverses its predecessor's judgment about which meaning has historical priority, shifting *nauseous* as "nauseating" to the first (earlier) position:

> **nauseous** *adj* **1 :** causing nausea : SICKENING **2 :** affected with nausea or disgust

The other significant change in the *Eighth Collegiate*'s treatment of *nauseous* is its replacing of the one-word definition "NAUSEATED" with a five-word descriptive definition. Though the *Seventh Collegiate* equated *nauseous* in that sense with *nauseated*, it didn't define the latter word; instead readers were left to surmise the meaning of *nauseated* from the dictionary's three-definition entry for *nauseate*:

> **nauseate** *vt* **1 :** to become affected with nausea **2 :** to feel disgust ~ *vi* **:** to affect with nausea or disgust

In the absence of a separate entry for *nauseated*—and given that the verb *nauseate* had the past-tense form *nauseated* for all three meanings given in the entry for *nauseate*—readers were left at sea with the *Seventh Collegiate*'s one-word primary definition of *nauseous*; it's easy to see why Merriam-Webster saw the need to improve on that definition for the *Eighth Collegiate*.

One point that frequently goes unnoticed in discussions of *nauseous* is that, all along, the verb *nauseate* could be understood in both the "cause nausea" sense and the "feel nausea" sense. The *Sixth Collegiate* (for example) has this entry for the verb:

> **nauseate** *v.t. & i.* To affect or become affected  with nausea; disgust; sicken.

The *Ninth Collegiate* (1983)—the edition that introduced the first-occurrence date feature in its word entries—tinkered with the first definition of *nauseous*, but not with the second:

> **nauseous** adj (1612) **1 :** causing nausea or disgust : NAUSEATING **2 :** affected with nausea or disgust

The *Ninth Collegiate* also marks the appearance of the first version of the usage note that Lynn quotes in another answer to this question. Here is how MW words the original usage note:

> ***usage*** Those who insist that *nauseous* can properly be used only in sense 1 are in error. Current evidence shows these facts: *nauseous* is most frequently used to mean physically affected with nausea; extended use is quite a bit less frequent. Use of *nauseous* in sense 1 is much more often figurative than literal, and this use appears to be losing ground to *nauseating*. There seems to be little use of *nauseated* except by those who prescribe it in place of *nauseous*.

In the *Tenth Collegiate* (1993) the definitions of *nauseous* are identical to those in the *Ninth Collegiate*. The usage note, however, shows some significant alterations (rendered in bold below):

> ***usage*** Those who insist that *nauseous* can properly be used only in sense 1 **and that in sense 2 it is an error for *nauseated* are mistaken**. Current evidence shows these facts: *nauseous* is most frequently used to mean physically affected with nausea, **usu. after a linking verb such as feel or become; figurative** use is quite a bit less frequent. Use of *nauseous* in sense 1 is much more often figurative than literal, and this use appears to be losing ground to *nauseating*. ***Nauseated*, while not rare, is less common than *nauseous* in sense 2.**

Like the *Tenth Collegiate*, the *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003) retains the *Ninth Collegiate*'s definitions unchanged. But it, too, substantially revises the usage note. In this case the few but crucial changes occur in the final sentence of the note (again rendered in bold below):

> ***usage*** Those who insist that *nauseous* can properly be used only in sense 1 and that in sense 2 it is an error for *nauseated* are mistaken. Current evidence shows these facts: *nauseous* is most frequently used to mean physically affected with nausea, usu. after a linking verb such as feel or become; figurative use is quite a bit less frequent. Use of *nauseous* in sense 1 is much more often figurative than literal, and this use appears to be losing ground to *nauseating*. *Nauseated* **is used more widely** than *nauseous* in sense 2.

Over a period of about 65 years, Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series doesn't just record (in the *Seventh Collegiate*) a shift from *nauseous* defined as having only the meaning "Causing, or fitted to cause, nausea; disgusting" to *nauseous* having two meanings: "causing nausea or disgust : NAUSEATING" and "affected with nausea or disgust." It also records (beginning in the *Ninth Collegiate*) the predictable demise of *nauseous* in the sense of "nauseating" in favor of the unambiguous word *nauseating*; and perhaps more surprisingly, it rather grudgingly records (over the span of the *Ninth*, *Tenth*, an *Eleventh Collegiates*) the rise of the word *nauseated* as a seemingly unambiguous alternative to *nauseous* in the sense of "affected with nausea or disgust."

On this record, it appears that the emergence of *nauseous* as "nauseated" in a sphere previously occupied solely by *nauseous* as "nauseating" led to a significant level of user flight away from the use of *nauseous* to indicate either sense of the word, in favor of words (*nauseating* and *nauseated*) that were perceived to be completely unambiguous. Whether *nauseated* is in fact technically unambiguous is debatable, but in popular usage I've never heard anyone say, for example, "The food was so nauseated that I couldn't eat it."

---

***What the Ngram results say***

An Ngram chart over the years 1800–2005 for *nauseate* (blue line) *nauseated* (red line), *nauseating* (green line), and *nauseous* (yellow line) tells a somewhat different story:

[image]

Most notable here is the steady but cumulatively severe decline in the frequency of *nauseous* from 1800 or so until about 1940, followed by a flattening out over the next 40 years and a slight rise since 1980. Tightly bunched with *nauseous* in the results for the period from 1920 to 2005 are *nauseating* and *nauseated*, while *nauseate* remains far less common than the other three words.

The most striking thing about the Ngram results for 1949–2003 is how flat everything generally is:

> [image]

It's rather astonishing that during this period (in the United States) a revolution in the accepted meaning of *nauseous* occurred. Looking at the portion of the chart representing those years, an observer would probably conclude that nothing much had happened to *nauseous* during most of that interval of time.

---

***Conclusions***

Today *nauseous* has two meanings: the old one ("sickening") that many people have stopped using *nauseous* to signify, preferring instead to use the unambiguous word *nauseating*; and the newer one ("made sick") that many people do use *nauseous* to signify but that others now prefer to use the effectively unambiguous word *nauseated* to signify. The history of *nauseous* thus illustrates how language sometimes adapts, shifts, or reverses the meaning of longtime words, and how speakers and writers sometimes respond to ambiguity with further changes in word choice and usage.