# Word for the vomit-y feeling you get for eating too much fatty food

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

I had bacon for breakfast, pork chop for lunch, if I see another meat, I'd vomit. I've reached my limit.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: *Stomach-turning*? Wait.. did I make a pun? ;)

Comment: Related question, [What's the difference between nauseous and nauseated?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125961/whats-the-difference-between-nauseous-and-nauseated).

Comment: There are numerous euphemisms and slang terms for *nausea*, such as "stomach churning", "queasy", "bilious", "green around the gills".

Comment: I once heard someone use the term 'meat-sweats'

Comment: @patrick that's not an uncommon term but has little to do with nausea, and tends to relate to an excessively or abnormally meaty meal.

Comment: In general, use of the word ***nauseous*** has [massively declined over the past couple of centuries.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nauseous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnauseous%3B%2Cc0) The specific usage ***I feel nauseous = I feel like I'm about to vomit*** has [gained a lot of traction in recent decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+feel+nauseous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20nauseous%3B%2Cc0). But it sounds very American compared to ***queasy***.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

> **nausea**, *n.*
>   1. a. A feeling of sickness with an inclination to vomit; an occurrence of such a feeling.

["nausea, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125412?redirectedFrom=nausea (accessed January 01, 2016).]

Don't spend it all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

> [queasy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/queasy)

means suffering from nausea, a stomach distress with *distaste for food and an urge to vomit*.

> "...if I eat any more meat, I'd vomit. I'm feeling **queasy**."

---

A good but more formal synonym is

> [nauseated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseated)

or more commonly

> [nauseous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nauseous)

Note that the latter means literally 'nausea inducing', but commonly used instead to mean 'having nausea'. I can't recommend one way or the other, because though 'nauseated' is correct to mean 'I have nausea', it is not as often used as 'nauseous' for the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

crapulence - eating or drinking too much

> n. 
> 1. Sickness caused by excessive eating or drinking. ([American
>   Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=crapulence&submit.x=0&submit.y=0))